# Can Autopep8 Support `source python django` in the grammar?

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, autopep8

I am using `atom` with `django` and `python-autopep8` package for code formatting,

In Atom [grammar-selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRlWE.png)

The package work fine with files uses `source python`.

My question is there a way to use autopep8 with files uses`source python django` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. please, explain it more and share your codes with us.

Comment: I'm using the "Django-atom" package and I have to switch to "source.python" grammar to use atom-python-autopep8
package.